# Which standard c++ type can I use to represent an epoch time with millisecond precision?

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++-chrono

I am parsing messages from a log file and I'd like to store the timestamp associated with each message in a struct field so that I can compare the order of messages. I'm not sure what type I can/should use. The log messages have the seconds since epoch and additional milliseconds for precision.

Can I use std::chrono::time_point? How can I instantiate a time_point from 2 integer counts of

1. seconds since epoch
2. additional milliseconds

Is there another std type I could/should use?

Comment: Can you not just use `uint64_t`? Set it to `time_since_epoch_in_sec*1000+residual_milliseconds` and it will be milliseconds since epoch. `time_point` and `duration` are simply wrappers around some numerics.

Comment: Yes, you can use `std::chrono::time_point`.  You also seem to be interested in `std::chrono:: milliseconds`.  The two can be added.  Have you researched this?

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the docs for time_point, but it wasn't clear to me how to construct a time_point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use system_clock and that you know how to extract seconds and milliseconds to a time_t variable, you can do this:

```
time_t timestamp_sec = 1678369127;
time_t timestamp_ms = 100;

auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(timestamp_sec) + std::chrono::milliseconds(timestamp_ms);
```

time will be `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` with your timestamp. You can test it via

```
std::cout << std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time).time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
```

Which will yield `1678369127100` as the output